# ClassCastExpection occuring in Clojure

Tags: clojure

To preface this, I'm very new to Clojure. I was wondering why I'm getting a ClassCastExpection on this piece of code. I've looked at it and syntactically and logically it looks correct?

Clojure Code:

```
; (load-file "cje842asg1.clj")
(def lstnum '(76 85 71))
; 2a
(defn sum [list] (
        (if (empty? list) 
            0
            (+ (first list (sum (rest list))))
        )
    )
)
; if empty return zero, else add the first num in list and pass in the 
; rest.

(sum lstnum)
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Could you point out what line of code has the extra brace?

Comment: The second `(` on the first line of the function definition (along with its matching `)`) are causing you to call the evaluated number as a function.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense!

Comment: Unrelated comment: Be careful with your names. `list` is a function in clojure.core. In your code here, this does not cause any issues but it's easy to run into problems, that for a beginner might lead to weird and hard to debug errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code has 2 separate errors.

The first is calling `(first list (sum (rest list)))` which is calling `first` with 2 arguments when you meant to make the second part the second argument to `+`.

The other one leading to the actual exception is the extra `()` around the function body. Note the `((if ...))` which means you are trying to call whatever the `if` returns as a function. In this case it is returning a number, leading to the `class java.lang.Long cannot be cast to class clojure.lang.IFn` error.

The corrected version would be

```
(defn sum [list]
  (if (empty? list)
    0
    (+ (first list)
       (sum (rest list)))))
```

Moving the arguments to `+` into separate lines makes it easier to read in this case (IMHO).

Comment: So it should look like this ``` (+ first list (sum (rest list))) ``` instead of ``` (first list (sum (rest list))) ```?

Comment: This was it! Thank you so much!